# Converting from an object-creating loop to a runBlock with a wait between object creation

Tags: ios, swift, object, sprite-kit, 2d-games

Sorry, very new to swift, and coding in general so this may be a beginner question.  I currently have the code below creating arrows around a circle.  How can I convert this so that all of the arrows spawn 1 second after the last, until they've all been created?  I was told by a user in another thread this would have to be accomplished using a runBlock and an SKAction.sequence but I'm only barely familiar with these.  Could I get some help?  Thanks! (:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

 self.spawnArrows()

}

func spawnArrows() {

 for var i = 0; i < 36; i++ {

     let arrow = self.createArrow(specificPointOnCircle(Float(self.frame.size.width), center: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), angle: Float(i * 10)))
     self.addChild(arrow)

 }
}

func specificPointOnCircle(radius:Float, center:CGPoint, angle:Float) -> CGPoint {

let theta = angle * Float(M_PI) / 180
let x = radius * cosf(theta)
let y = radius * sinf(theta)
return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x) + center.x, y: CGFloat(y) + center.y)

}

func createArrow(position: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {

let arrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Arrow.png")
arrow.zPosition = 2
arrow.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 2 * 0.12, height: self.frame.size.width * 0.025)
arrow.position = position
return arrow

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your `spawnArrows` method like below

```
func spawnArrows() {

    var list = [SKAction]()

    for var i = 0; i < 36; i++ {
        let create = SKAction.runBlock { [unowned self] in 
            let arrow = self.createArrow(self.specificPointOnCircle(Float(self.frame.size.width), center: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), angle: Float(i * 10)))
            self.addChild(arrow)
        }
        list.append(create)

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
        list.append(wait)
    }

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence(list)
    self.runAction(sequence)
}
```

As you can see now I am using the `for loop` to create a *list of actions*.

1. The first added action does contain the code to create the first arrow
2. Then there is an action to wait 1 second
3. Then the action to add the second arrow
4. And so on...

After the `for loop` does end, the list of actions is transformed into a `sequence` and finally executed.

Let me know if it does work.

Comment: Thank you this is working as far as a wait timer between creating the arrows!  They're just no longer being created around the circle, instead they're only coming from the right side of the screen.  I imagine I can fix this by setting a global variable for the angle and then adding it into the for loop along with a manipulation of the variable

Comment: Ahh yes I just changed the angle from (i + 10) to a global variable of i instead.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @appzYourLife Not sure if you intentionally left this because of simplicity, but using self like that inside of a closure will create strong reference cycle and using something like SKAction.runBlock{ [unowned self] in /*do your stuff here*/} or removing all actions in scene's willMoveFromView method will prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Whirlwind: I updated my code, thank you for pointing it out.